# How to bypass click events on a View in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, onclicklistener, parallax

Suppose I have a simple transperent `View` and an `ImageView` under it. The transparent `View` completely covers the `ImageView`. Now I want my `ImageView` to recieve click events, but since the `View` is blocking it, is there any way to bypass/disable click events on `View` so that those clicks are accepted by `ImageView` ? One will say why not just treat the `View` as your `ImageView` for click events and put an `onClickListener()` on `View`, but the thing is, underlying `ImageView` will scroll away in some cases and `View` will still remain on screen,and that can cause a problem. 
[This transparent View is used to achieve `parallax` scroll effect.I'm using this library -> https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView
And I'm unable to get clicks on `ImageView`.]

Comment: `android:clickable="false"`

Comment: or make it so that the ImageView is on top

Comment: Karaokyo can't make it below ImageView as it is the part of animation